# RESTful API authorization/permissions using OPTIONS

Tags: rest, permissions, authorization, api-design, http-options-method

Are HTTP `OPTIONS` requests appropriate to determine a user's authorization?

I have seen HTTP `OPTIONS` requests used for preflight to check if a request is valid, but is it okay to use it to determine what access a user has to a specific resource?

## Use case

A resource is display on a page. There is an edit form uses `PUT` to update the resource. If a request to `OPTIONS /resource/1` shows it accepts `PUT`, an edit button is displayed.

## Questions

1. Is an `OPTIONS` request suitable to the return the verbs that a specific user has access to determine authorization/permissions?
2. Should `OPTIONS` requests header information be used in frontend code (or just preflight vaidation)?
3. Are there any standards for determining an authenticated user's permissions via REST API?

Comment: Did you ever settle on this approach?

Comment: @LeeviGraham I created a proof of concept implementation for a project, but chickened out before putting it in production. Ended up just making another endpoint to fetch for user roles.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Mozilla docs for OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) answer to your question is "yes". However, we need to add Authorization checks for all HTTP Methods - GET, POST, PUT & DELETE, since actual data is accessed by these Methods.

Here are the reasons:

1. Usually OPTIONS is called before POST by Web Browsers (for CORS checks). Not sure this is called by all API clients (For eg. server to server communication)
2. Even if you add Authorization support for OPTIONS, you need to add it for all remaining methods of HTTP.